# What does "catch a crosstown bus" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading a question on Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange: [What does it mean to long the convexity of options?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/15457) One of the answers there reads:

[image: Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange answer]

The answer is wrong, but notice the comment:

> Yeah, but where do I catch a crosstown bus?

What does "catch a crosstown bus" mean?

Comment: Asking about something randomly chosen and irrelevant to the topic is a way of saying the answer is not helpful. Like saying "What has that go to do with the price of fish?"

Comment: The answer above the comment, with -4 votes, is considered unhelpful and incomplete.